# How can I seperate one column into multiple columns depending on their value when selecting it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-columns, sql-manager

I have a table called assignment_answers, which has the following attributes:
*assignment_answers_id, question_id and order*. The order is an attribute, which can take a value from 0 to 9. 
I would like for every value that it can take to make it be displayed in a different column. For instance when the order has value 0, then I want it to be displayed in a column called *number0*. When it has value 1 I want it to be displayed in a column called *number1*.

Could someone help me with that? So far I have tried this but it does not work:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN assessment_answers.order = 0 
             THEN(
              select aq.order as number0
              from assessment_answers)
              END)
       (CASE WHEN assessment_answers.order = 1 
             THEN(
              select aq.order as number1
              from assessment_answers)
              END)
FROM assessment_answers
```

I get an error saying: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 6:        (CASE WHEN assessment_questions."order" = 1

SAMPLE DATA

```
assignment_answers_id     question_id    order
 1                            1           0
 2                            1           0
 3                            2           1
```

desired output:

```
assignment_answers_id     question_id    order0  order1
 1                            1           0       null
 2                            1           0       null
 3                            2           null     1
```

Comment: @D-Shih I updated the question

Comment: Ok I wrote an answer hope can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use normal `CASE WHEN`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT assignment_answers_id,
       question_id,
       (CASE WHEN order = 0 THEN order END) order0,
       (CASE WHEN order = 1 THEN order END) order1
FROM assessment_answers
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84f6e/2/0)**:

```
| assignment_answers_id | question_id | order0 | order1 |
|-----------------------|-------------|--------|--------|
|                     1 |           1 |      0 | (null) |
|                     2 |           1 |      0 | (null) |
|                     3 |           2 | (null) |      1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select (aa.order = 0)::int as order_0, 
       (aa.order = 1)::int as order_1, 
       (aa.order = 2)::int as order_2, 
       . . .
from  assessment_answers aa;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I get an error saying : ERROR:  type "order_0" does not exist